# UITextView in UITableView, Smooth Expand using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, autolayout

I have an editable `UITextView` in every `UITableViewCell`.

The `UITextViews` resize fine to pre-loaded text (calculated via `heightForRowAtIndexPath`) but I'm not sure how to get the smooth-resizing using `AutoLayout` when adding text dynamically. It just seems to get cut off.

Using `AutoLayout`, how can I smooth-resize a `UITableViewCell` and `UITextView` to fit the text being entered into the `UITextView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A table view cell doesn't derive its height via layout constraints, but via the delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You can probably achieve the effect you are after like this:

- Pin your text view to the top and bottom of the cell's content view
- On your text view delegate methods, recalculate the text size as it is entered
- If a change in size is required, update wherever in your model the heights are stored
- Call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on your table view. This will cause it to requery the heights, and animate to the new size (by extension, adjusting the size of the text view as well).

Answer (score 7):

Accepted answer is the deprecated one, there is a clean solution for this in iOS 8 sdk

In viewDidLoad, tell the tableView to automatically calculate row heights:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0f;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Implement the textViewDidChange: method of the UITextViewDelegate protocol, and tell the tableView to repaint itself every time the text is edited:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

And don’t forget to set the UITextView delegate somewhere, either in Storyboard/IB or in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: